# こばれた means what?

Tags: grammar

I was reading a conversation and I found the word "こばれた" and I searched in dictionaries online and I didn't find it !

someone was asking the other person "why the Persian carpet came to japan ? "

and he answered

16せいきにポルトガルのふねではこばれたそうです.

so what's "こばれた” here ?

I found "こばれたこと” means "spill" but it doesn't suit the conversation !

Answer (score 7):

> 16せいきにポルトガルのふねで**はこばれた**そうです。
>   
> Appears that it was carried on a Portuguese ship in the 16th century.

It's 運{はこ}ばれた you needed to look for, and not こばれた.